# DT in Shiny, multi-values filtering (search a list of strings seperated by semi-colon)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Does `DT::renderDataTable` have the feature of column filtering a list of items separated by semi-colon?

Take this as an example https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-filter/

Would it be possible to search the "am" column by typing or paste in

```
manual;automatic;
```

as one multiple value?

For the moment, it seems only support a selection of drop-down list one item after another like the following screenshot.

[image: dorp down menu of column filter]

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility for now is you convert the factor column to character and use regular expressions to search the column. See [this example](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/007-search.html) for how to use regular expressions.

For a character column, the regular expression can be like `^(automatic|manual)$` to match `automatic` and `manual`.